# Yahoo! Mail is not letting me attach files to send...

Tags: yahoo-mail, attachment

Yahoo! Mail is not letting me attach files to send.  This problem started suddenly and inexplicably on 18 October 2011.  I have tried multiple browsers.  I have tried re-installing browsers.  I have tried to attach both `.docx` and `.doc` files (files that are clearly well below the maximum allowed size).

Sometimes the system just hangs and sometimes I get an error message in red type (sorry, can't recall the specific text of the message).  Has anyone else experienced this?

More importantly, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Seems you are not the only one: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111019061525AAmZFeD

Comment: It's either localized or it got solved, because I just sent an email with attachments and it worked just fine.

Comment: This question is about an old issue from a specific moment in time. It is unlikely to help any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem Yahoo email. Found if I went to the IE tool bar and clicked on "tools" and brought up my "add on mangaement" screen. From there I disabled the Adobe shock wave softwear. Now I could once again attach files to my email. This problem developed when my Yahoo was up graded. Good Luck.